# Get the number of all possible 3x2 matrices that fulfill condition

Tags: python, matrix, combinatorics

I want to get the number of all possible 3x2 matrices such that

- Each element of the matrix is either 0, 1, or 2.
- None of the 3 rows of the matrix has the same elements in all entries (a_{i1} != a_{i2} for i=1,2,3).
- None of the 2 columns of the matrix has the same elements in all his entries (a_{1j} = a_{2j} = a_{3j} is never the case for j=1,2).

Basically if 0, 1, and 2 are represented by the colors 0 = Red, 1 = Green, 2 = Blue, then you can generate the following matrices:

[image]

Prohibited matrix configurations:

[image]

How do I get the number of all possible matrix with this configuration? Or how do I generate them all?

Comment: Fun fact: **555** matrices are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate using recursion and backtrack. Each time you will try to fill up one of the cell by one of three color and then  call the next cell . If finally all the colors are filled up then check whether the matrix is valid or not.

```python
def recursion(Matrix ,i ,j):
    # Validation check
    if i==3:
        if  Matrix[0][0]==Matrix[1][0] and Matrix[1][0]==Matrix[2][0]:
            return;
        if  Matrix[0][1]==Matrix[1][1] and Matrix[1][1]==Matrix[2][1]:
            return;
        if  Matrix[0][0]==Matrix[0][1] or Matrix[1][0]==Matrix[1][1] or Matrix[2][0]==Matrix[2][1]:
            return
        print("Matrix : ")
        for row in Matrix:
            for val in row:
                print '{:4}'.format(val),
            print
        return

    # Shifting to the next row
    if j==2:
        recursion(Matrix,i+1,0)
        return

    # Filling up the current cell by one of {0,1,2}
    for color in range(3):
        Matrix[i][j]=color
        recursion(Matrix,i,j+1)
    return


Matrix=[[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(3)]
recursion(Matrix,0,0)
```